# Some function notations in JavaScript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding syntax that I've been coming across in JavaScript.

What does it mean if I define functions or variables inside a context like the one just below?
(source: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/)

```
(function($) {
  $.confirm = function() {
   ...
  }

  $.confirm.hide = function() {
   ...
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Also, what the `$.` mean in the function `$.confirm`? Also, with `$.confirm.hide`, I feel that there is some jQuery object involved.

Comment: I bet this same question has been asked a dozen times in the last week.

Comment: JavaScript is like an onion...When you cut into it, it makes you cry.

Comment: @zzzzBov Onions won't make you cry if you wash it off first.

Comment: @amnotiam : I am sure its a common question which is why searching for exactly what I wanted was not easy. Sorry if this was spam for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping a function in parens then executed using to more parents `(function() {])();` is a n immediately invoked function. By passing in jQuery within the 2nd set of parens you pass in a paramter which you are you passing in as `$`.

`$.confirm` is just a method of the `jQuery` object

```
(function($) { // $ = jQuery
  $.confirm = function() {  // <-- set method of jQuery
   ...
  }


  $.confirm.hide = function() { // <-- set method of confirm
   ...
  }

   // usage
  $.confirm();
  // or
  jQuery.confirm();
})(jQuery); // pass in the jQuery object to the function via immediate invocation
```

Many libraries, like jQuery, use $ as a shortcut variable because it stands out from typical variables used in javascript.

Comment: Got a question. Why should I need to define a function as a method of the jQuery object? Why not a simple function? Is there a difference?

Comment: Typically, make `jQuery` plugins that extend the `jQuery prototype` aka `jQuery.fn`. Plugins are built for reusability and are often related to `jQuery` usage.  If you had a function that had nothing to do with `jQuery` functionality then yes, a simple function would make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

> What does it mean if I define functions or variables inside a context like the one just below?

It means that you've defined a function, and ideally prevented global pollution (unfortunately, it wont actually help against global warming). There's a lot going on, so I'll try to split it out into a few parts:

```
(function($) {
  $.confirm = function() {
   ...
  }

  $.confirm.hide = function() {
   ...
  }
})(jQuery);
```

## Part 1 - Closure

JavaScript is not like most other C-style languages, blocks<sup>1</sup> do not get a new variable scope. In many C-style languages, a variable defined within a block will only exist within that block:

Some other C-style pseudo-code

```
function foo() {
  var a = 1;
  if (somecondition) {
    var b = 2;
    output(a, b); //1, 2
  }
  output(a, b); //throws some sort of exception because 'b' isn't defined.
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function foo() {
  var a = 1;
  if (somecondition) {
    var b = 2;
    output(a, b); //1, 2
  }
  output(a, b); //1, 2 due to variable hoisting
}
```

In JavaScript, variables don't have block scope, instead they have functional scope. Any defined variable is owned by it's first function ancestor. The instantiation of the variable is moved to the top of the function when the script is analyzed (this is called "variable hoisting"), so although you may have written `foo` (as seen above), what it's actually interpreted as is as follows:

```
function foo() {
  var a, b;
  a = 1;
  if (somecondition) {
    b = 2;
    output(a, b);
  }
  output(a, b);
}
```

If there is no parent function of the variable, it's added to the global object, which in web browsers is `window`:

```
<script>
var a = 1;
output(window.a); //1 - set because there's no parent function
</script>
```

functions declared using `function [some name]() {...}` are treated similarly.

```
<script>
  function foo() {return 1;}
  output(window.foo()); //1
</script>
```

If you work on a large project and all variables are defined without a parent function, multiple programmers might use `var foo`, and would overwrite `window.foo`, which would lead to buggy and unstable code.

JavaScript allows for the creation of self-executing anonymous functions:

```
( function (){} )();
-or-
( function () {}() );
```

This is useful because it creates a new function context with which variables and functions can be defined without polluting the global namespace<sup>2</sup>. Functions like this that *close* over a set of variables/functions are called **closures**.

Parameters can be defined just like any other function, and they are passed to the function in the last set of parens. This explains your first and last lines of code:

```
(function ($) {
  ...
}(jQuery));
```

A new function context is created, and jQuery is being passed into the context into the variable `$`. This is used for aliasing `jQuery` to the shortcut `$`, which is a valid character for variable and function names.

## Part 2 - Everything's an Object

Everything in JavaScript is an object, except for `null` and `undefined`. Mutable objects can have properties and methods set on them. Object literals (`{}`), array literals (`[]`), functions (`function(){}`), and objects created using constructors (`new String('foo')`) are all mutable objects.

```
var a = {};
a.foo = 'bar';

function b() {}
b.fizz = 'buzz';
```

This means that the `jQuery` object, which is a `function`, and has been aliased to `$`, can have new properties added to it:

```
$.confirm = function () {...};
```

And after the new `$.confirm` function is created, `$.confirm` is an object that can have properties added to it:

```
$.confirm.hide = function () {...};
```

If you wanted to call the `confirm` function outside of the closure, you'd write:

```
jQuery.confirm();
```

If you wanted to call the `hide` function outside of the closure, you'd write:

```
jQuery.confirm.hide();
```

<sub>1: a block is a section of code contained within `{}` characters, such as `if (...) {/* block region */}`, `switch() {}`, `function () {}`, `while () {}`, etc. Don't confuse object literals, which instantiate new objects, with blocks.

2: global namespace pollution is simply adding too many new variables on the global object, which is typically `window`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The code creates an anonymous function and calls it with jQuery as the argument. It's the same as

```
function addProperties($) {
  $.confirm = function() {
   ...
  }

  $.confirm.hide = function() {
   ...
  }
}
addProperties(jQuery);
```

`$` is a valid variable name in javascript, and the function is adding properties to it. It's the same as:

```
function addProperties(j) {
  j.confirm = function() {
   ...
  }

  j.confirm.hide = function() {
   ...
  }
}
addProperties(jQuery);
```

jQuery is an object, and using the dot operator accesses its properties. For example, an object of apple might look like:

```
var apple = {
    color: 'red',
    height: 55,
    foodType: 'fruit'
};

alert(apple.foodType); // alerts 'fruit'
```

You might have some misconceptions about jQuery based on your question. jQuery isn't a feature of javascript, it's a library of code that creates a large object called `jQuery`, though it can also be accessed as `$`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is the name of the parameter to the function that is used to create the scope, and because it's called with the `jQuery` object, `$` will be equal to `jQuery` inside the scope. (By default the global name `$` is also assigned `jQuery`, but this way of using a scope enables you to use `$` inside it even if jQUery is used in compatibility mode, where the global `$` identifier is not set.)

So, assigning a function to `$.confirm` will in effect assign it to `jQuery.confirm`.

As functions are objects in Javascript, you can add properties to them. That's why you can assign a function to `$.confirm.hide`, which is of course `jQuery.confirm.hide`.

After that code has run, you can call the `jQuery.confirm` function, and the `jQuery.confirm.hide` function.